# Is there an adjective describing the feeling of touching a cool, water-condensated surface?

Tags: adjectives

I'm trying to describe the peculiar feeling when you touch a cool, water-condensated surface (like a soda can freshly out of the fridge, the indoor side of a window in winter, etc.). It's kind of an unpleasant feeling because you'd get your hand wet and cold touching it. Any good suggestions?

Comment: You feel a chill.

Comment: The can is *dewy*. The absolutely most repugnant sensation in the world is dewy (wet) grass on one's bare feet.

Comment: @DanBron If you can't think of any more repugnant sensation than that yours is not a fertile imagination.

Comment: @WS2 Brave words for a man who's at no risk of being asked to walk barefoot across wet grass in the near future!

Comment: @DanBron - That actually feels good.  Have you tried barefoot in snow?

Comment: @HotLicks Hey man, I don't judge anyone's kinks, you pervert ;)

Answer (score 1):

**dank**

[Free dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/dank)

- The kitchen felt dank and chilly in the cold of the winter.

Answer (score 1):

**creepily clammy**

might give the readers the right feeling :-)